# How do I restart a new game in No Mans Sky? (PC)

Tags: pc, no-mans-sky

I never got the blueprint for a hyper drive parts and now I am stuck in my first star system. I have tried deleting local game content (with and without steam cloud sync) and going into the programs and deleting everything related to NMS. Please help.